# How do i take a specific last value from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So, I query a database and I succeed with this query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM log WHERE dokumen_name LIKE "%A12345%" ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1';
```

and the result is this:
[image: value]

Then I want to take from the red box to put it in here:

```
<h3>di Posisi sekarang: <?php echo $row["lokasi"];  ?></h3>
```

but it did not show up, how do I do that?

Comment: Lokasi <> lokasi in PHP

Answer (score 2):

```
<h3>di Posisi sekarang: <?php echo $row["Lokasi"];  ?></h3>
```

Don't forget capitals

Answer (score 0):

My code is right, turn out i query after `<h3>di Posisi sekarang: <?php echo $row["lokasi"];  ?></h3>` this code, so it will not work. so, i put the query before the di Posisi sekarang: `<?php echo $row["lokasi"];  ?></h3>` and it works. soory for my misconception.